# Scope issue : how to see (not access neither modify !) a private attribute from outside its class?

Tags: c++, class, object, scope, private

I'd like to know if there's any way to *see* (and **not access neither modify**) a private member from outside its class ?

```
template <typename type_>
class OBJ1
{
  //methods
};

class OBJ2
{
  private:
    OBJ1<int> my_obj;
};

class OBJ3
{
  public:
    template <typename type_>
    void magic_method(OBJ1<type_> obj)
    {
      //with another intermediate class, call one of OBJ1's public methods
      //anotherClass::call(obj);
    }
};
```

Obviously this does not work, as G++ does not know what is `my_obj` within `class OBJ3`. Is there a way to make this code compile ? Like forward declaration or something ? And again, other classes just need to know that "OBJ1 declared objects" exist.

Thanks !

Comment: the argument of the method declaration shouldn't be (OBJ1<int> my_obj)? my_obj is not any type name.

Comment: @Kurospidey Yes, of course. I'll edit my post !

Comment: this code compiles what is the problem?

Comment: why don't you just make OBJ3 a friend class of OBJ2? That way you could access OBJ2 private section (other solution is changing order between OBJ3 and OBJ2 declarations and make magic_method a friend method of OBJ2). As i don't think you can see (see is another way of access) a private member of a class from an outside class.

Comment: @Denis Ermolin I'm not sure, but I think he's trying to access the OBJ1<int> member of OBJ2...

Comment: The impression I've got is that @Patouf is confused about forward declarations. Forward declarations are about types, not names of objects. `my_obj` is the name of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// call one of OBJ1's *public* methods
```

You can easily make that work, as show below. What's the actual problem, and what does `OBJ2` have to do with anything? Post code that displays the private access error you're concerned about.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename type_>
class OBJ1
{
  public:
  void print_type_name() {
    std::cout << typeid(type_).name() << "\n";
  }
};

/*
class OBJ2
{
  private:
    OBJ1<int> my_obj;
};
*/

class anotherClass {
  public:
    template <typename type_>
    static void call(OBJ1<type_> obj) {
        obj.print_type_name();
    }
};

class OBJ3
{
  public:
    template <typename type_>
    void magic_method(OBJ1<type_> obj)
    {
      //with another intermediate class, call one of OBJ1's public methods
      anotherClass::call(obj);
    }
};

int main() {
    OBJ3 obj3;
    OBJ1<int> obj1;
    OBJ1<double> objd;
    obj3.magic_method(obj1);
    obj3.magic_method(objd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
void magic_method(OBJ1<int>& my_obj)
{
  //with another intermediate class, call one of OBJ1's public methods
}
```

or, if you want `OBJ1` to be generic:

```
template<typename T>
void magic_method(OBJ1<T>& my_obj)
{
  //with another intermediate class, call one of OBJ1's public methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm  not sure exactly what you want... but If I understand correctly you want to access OBJ2 private section from within OBJ3.

```
template <typename type_>
class OBJ1
{
  //methods
};

template <typename type_>
class OBJ2
{
  private:
    OBJ1<type_> my_obj;
    friend class OBJ3;
};

class OBJ3
{
  public:
    template <typename type_>
    void magic_method(OBJ2<type_> obj)
    {
      std::cout << obj.my_obj;
      //with another intermediate class, call one of OBJ1's public methods
      //anotherClass::call(obj);
    }
}
```